# set EditText width in LinearLayout depend on TextView width

Tags: android, view, textview, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I have following snippet of code. only one `EditText` and `TextView` in horizontal `LinearLayout`. I want to set `EditText` width depend on the `TextView` width. If the width of `TextView` means Text increase need to adjust `EdiText` width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#224386"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_edittext"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in Advance.[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a `LinearLayout` or can you use `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I would use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#224386"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/titleTextView"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_edittext"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It will produce exactly the output you want.

Also notice that setting `gravity` to the `TextView` is useless as it wraps its content. The same applies to the `center_vertical` value for the `EditText`'s `gravity` because it also wraps its content height-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. then set textView to right and editText to left of textView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#224386"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_edittext"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```